# if an element in an MxN matrix is 0, its entire row and column is set to 0

Tags: c++

```
void zero(int a[][4],int m,int n){
bool row[m], col[n];
memset(row,false,sizeof(row));
memset(col,false,sizeof(col));
for(int i = 0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j= 0;j<n ; j++ )
    {
    if(a[i][j]==0){
        row[i]=true;
        col[j]=true;
    }    
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(row[i] || row[j])
        a[i][j]=0;
    }
} 

}
int main(){
int a[][4]={
{1,2,3,4},
{1,2,4,5},
{4,0,6,7},
{3,6,3,56},
}
zero(a,4,4);
for(int i = 0 ; i<4;i++){
for(int j = 0;j < 4 ; j++){
    cout << a[i][j]<<" " ;
}cout <<endl;
}
}
```

Write an algorithm such that if an element in an MxN matrix is 0, its entire row and column is set to 0.
   so here is my code. as you can see the a[2][1] = 0 , so row 2 and col 1 supposed to be 0. but my result is row 2 and col 2 are 0 . really confused ...please help

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Keep staring at your last `if` statement, until you see your bug.

Comment: I've tried debugger before I asked question here .

Comment: @CD-Key you didnt try hard enough :P. Did you follow Sams advice? I also had to look twice to realize what you want to do there

Comment: indent your code properly

Answer (score 5):

If you straight away start replacing rows and columns with 0s if a 0 is found in a row or column during traversal then ultimately whole array will become zero.

A correct solution is to store (row, col) indices pairs somewhere while traversing array and then make changes to array one by one by using those pairs after traversal is complete.

```
array = [
          [1 , 2, 3],
          [4 , 5, 0],
          [7 , 8, 9]
        ]

indices_pairs = [(row,col) for row in range(len(array)) for col in range(len(array[0])) if array[row][col] == 0]


for indices_pair in indices_pairs:
    row, col = indices_pair

    for i in range(len(array[0])):
    array[row][i] = 0

    for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i][col] = 0


print(array)

[
 [1 , 2, 0],
 [0 , 0, 0],
 [7 , 8, 0]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution :

```
public static void setZeros(int[][] matrix) {
    int[] row = new int[matrix.length];
    int[] column = new int[matrix[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                row[i] = 1;
                column[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            if ((row[i] == 1 || column[j] == 1)) {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Full Code :)**

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a[][]= new int[3][3];
            int x=0;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                    a[i][j]=s.nextInt();
                }
            }
            int[] row = new int[a.length];
            int[] column = new int[a[0].length];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                    if (a[i][j] == 0) {
                        row[i] = 1;
                        column[j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                    if ((row[i] == 1 || column[j] == 1)) {
                        a[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                   System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably pretty late to this. But, here is my answer in python :)

```
import numpy as np
def reset_row_col(input_matrix):
    input_matrix = np.array(input_matrix)
    row_num, col_num = input_matrix.shape
    flag = 0 
    for i in range(row_num):
        for j in range(col_num):
            if input_matrix[i][j] == 0:
                input_matrix[i,:] = 0
                input_matrix[:,j] = 0
                flag = 1
                break
        if flag == 1:
            break
    return input_matrix
```

Comment: Notice that the question asks for a C++ solution.

Answer (score -1):

You call a function that verifies if your elements are zero, if they are they are replaced by "true", then inside this function you test to see if these elements exist, and if they do you set them to zero, of course everything will be zeros ;)

Comment: I have correct output for all row ( 0 and normal elements) , but the row (it dely one col)

Comment: *but the col(it dely one col )

Comment: @CD-Key ... you made the same mistake again (confusing row with col)

Comment: so in case you haven't sort it out: in you code you wrote row twice instead of col, Sam said it. Also if your goal is to zero all out if one value if zero you should have a loop like the first one which sets values in one go it would be ... less confusing

Comment: finally figured it out ...it because I wrote twice row as you mentioned ......my goal is : Write an algorithm such that if an element in an MxN matrix is 0, its entire row and column is set to 0.   for example 2x2 matrix :    " 2 3" "1 0 "  become to "2 0" " 0 0" .   anyway .. now it works now ..thanks for your help